# How can I build a composite video to scart converter?

Tags: converter, adapter, video, scart

I'm interested in building a composite to scart adapter.

How can I?

Comment: Don't. SCART is the worst connector ever designed. You should block any ports with a warning label.

Comment: Composite signal is already a part of SCART Pin 20 is composite signal and 17 is composite ground.

Comment: @pipe Nonsense! SCART is awesome.

Comment: @winny: SCART functionality was awesome back in the day.  The connectors themselves were crap.  I've got several leftovers laying around here where the housing broke or the wires got bent and broken.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SCART pinout you either use pin 17&19 for Scart to composite or 18&20 for composite to SCART.

I assume you are using a RCA jack for composite, thus the ring of it would be GND and the tip the signal.

[image: Scart Pinout]

Comment: Another question:does a modern lcd tv that support scart support this way of "injecting"composite?This tv doesnt have a composite in.

Comment: Its essentially the same signal but in a different connector. Thou you may run into problems if you try to mix NTSC or PAL but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

[Scart includes connections for composite video.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART)

All you have to do is to wire your composite video signal to pin 20 and the ground of your composite signal to pin 17.